# error in compiling code that call to rest service

Tags: java, rest, package

I trying to use this example and learn how to call to rest service,
when I put this code I getting error since the eclipse doesn't know 
the   **org.example.Customer;** .the error in definition Customer customer.
how can I import it to my project ?
I have tried to use the eclipse suggestion  without success. (fix project setup etc)

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.example.Customer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;


public class JerseyClient {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Client client = Client.create();
      WebResource resource =
        client.resource("http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers");

      // Get response as String
      String string = resource.path("1")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .get(String.class);
      System.out.println(string);

      // Get response as Customer
      Customer customer = resource.path("1") ------"*Here is the error in customer*-------
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .get(Customer.class);
      System.out.println(customer.getLastName() + ", "+ customer.getFirstName());

      // Get response as List<Customer>
      List<Customer> customers = resource.path("findCustomersByCity/Any%20Town")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .get(new GenericType<List<Customer>>(){});
      System.out.println(customers.size());
   }
}
```

I have used the code from this blog

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html

Comment: FYI ___your directory structure would help you get answers___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be

1: is the import statement `import org.example.Customer;` underlined in red?

2: the class `Customer` is that inside a jar? or another project in your workspace? or where is it located?

3: Are there any chances that there could be two jars on your classpath that contains the class `Customer`?

4: if its in a project, did you first build that project?

update , see in the [link here](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)

[image]

they have shown the packaging and deployment organization, see the Customer class is inside `CustomerService.jar` which is inside `CustomerService.war`. do you have these items?

Dude did you follow the tutorial well?

Comment: 1. yes 2. not sure 3. not sure

Comment: Cool, so underlined in red means , that the import path you have specified is incorrect, I.e. there is nothing on that path. Now tell me..where is the class Customer? in your workspace? haan @StefanStrooves ?\

Comment: no the class doesnt in my workspace I thought the the class  is coming from the  org.example.Customer package ,doesnt it ?

Comment: @StefanStrooves, yes it is comming. But where is that package? you know, java aint gonna look for `org.example.Customer` in your hard drive througout on its own ,n yea not on the internet as well in case you were just thinking.. ;) , you need to tell java, where to look for the required classes.. see my updated post for another hint

Answer (score 0):

If your `org.example.Customer` class in not in the same project in which you are creating this service the you can include it to classpath of your current project.

Just make sure that you have your directory structure like the one shown below (Used it from the link given by you in the question) .If its not like it then  that may be the cause of error.

[image]

Comment: can you guide me now please?

Comment: Since I new to eclipse can you show me how should I check it since I only paste the code to new class in new project...

Answer (score 0):

The blog you give the [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html) says:

> In our CustomerService session bean we created in [part 4](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html) we specified
>   that our RESTful service would use the path "/customers" using the
>   @Path annotation.

At which step are you?

Have you followed all steps?